# Elastic Search: including #/hashtags in search results

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Using elastic search's query DSL this is how I am currently constructing my query:

```
    elastic_sort = [
        { "timestamp": {"order": "desc" }},
        "_score",
        { "name": { "order": "desc" }},
        { "channel": { "order": "desc" }},
    ]

    elastic_query = {
    "fuzzy_like_this" : {
            "fields" : [ "msgs.channel", "msgs.msg", "msgs.name" ],
            "like_text" : search_string,
            "max_query_terms" : 10,
            "fuzziness": 0.7,
        }
    }

    res = self.es.search(index="chat", body={
        "from" : from_result, "size" : results_per_page,
        "track_scores": True,
        "query": elastic_query,
        "sort": elastic_sort,
    })
```

I've been trying to implement a filter or an analyzer that will allow the inclusion of "#" in searches (I want a search for "#thing" to return results that include "#thing"), but I am coming up short. The error messages I am getting are not helpful and just telling me that my query is malformed.

I attempted to incorporate the method found here : http://www.fullscale.co/blog/2013/03/04/preserving_specific_characters_during_tokenizing_in_elasticsearch.html but it doesn't make any sense to me in context.

Does anyone have a clue how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a mapping for you index? You can specify within your mapping to not analyze certain fields.

For example, a tweet mapping can be something like:

```
"tweet": {
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "msg": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "hashtags": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
  }
}
```

You can then perform a term query on "hashtags" for an exact string match, including "#" character.

If you want "hashtags" to be tokenized as well, you can always create a multi-field for "hashtags".